# Entity Framework: The entity type IMF_Main_Category is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Windows Service and it's just basically transferring data from one database to another. I am using `EntityConnectionStringBuilder()` on my dbcontext these are the branches where I will be transferring my data to.

```
public MirrorBranchesEntities(string db)
        : base(ConnectToSqlServer(db))
    {
    }

    public static string ConnectToSqlServer(string catalog)
    {
        var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = "(local)";
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = catalog;
        sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = "sa";
        sqlBuilder.Password = "Qwer0987";
        var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/MirrorBranches.csdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.ssdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.msl";

        return entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

My class itself is simple:

```
public static bool DistributeMerchandise(string db)
    {
        using (var anthillConsolidatorEntities = new AnthillConsolidatorEntities())
        {
            var mirrorBranches = new MirrorBranchesEntities(db);
            bool syncResult = false;

            //Brands
            if (anthillConsolidatorEntities.IMF_Main_Brands.Where(w => w.SyncedtoMirror == false).Count() == 0)
                return false;

            Library.WriteLog("[IMF_Brands] Synchronizing Brands");
            var brands = new IMF_Main_Brands();
            foreach (var item in anthillConsolidatorEntities.IMF_Main_Brands.Where(w => w.SyncedtoMirror == false))
            {
                try
                {
                    Library.WriteLog("[IMF_Brands] Processing " + item.Name);
                    brands.BrandID = item.BrandID;
                    brands.Name = item.Name;
                    brands.Type = item.Type;
                    brands.Active = item.Active;

                    mirrorBranches.IMF_Main_Brands.Add(brands);
                    mirrorBranches.SaveChanges();

                    item.SyncedtoMirror = true;
                    anthillConsolidatorEntities.SaveChanges();
                    syncResult = true;
                    Library.WriteLog("[IMF_Brands] " + item.Name + " Synced");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Library.WriteLog("Exception: [IMF_Brands] - " + ex);
                    syncResult = false;
                }
            }

            //Category
            if (anthillConsolidatorEntities.IMF_Main_Category.Where(w => w.SyncedtoMirror == false).Count() == 0)
                return false;

            Library.WriteLog("[IMF_Category] Synchronizing Category");
            var categories = new IMF_Main_Category();
            foreach (var item in anthillConsolidatorEntities.IMF_Main_Category.Where(w => w.SyncedtoMirror == false))
            {
                try
                {
                    Library.WriteLog("[IMF_Category] Processing " + item.Name);
                    categories.CategoryID = item.CategoryID;
                    categories.Name = item.Name;
                    categories.hasDimensions = item.hasDimensions;

                    mirrorBranches.IMF_Main_Category.Add(categories);
                    mirrorBranches.SaveChanges();

                    item.SyncedtoMirror = true;
                    anthillConsolidatorEntities.SaveChanges();
                    syncResult = true;
                    Library.WriteLog("[IMF_Category] " + item.Name + " Synced");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Library.WriteLog("Exception: [IMF_Category] - " + ex);
                    syncResult = false;
                }
            }
```

//end blocks below

Brands block work, but not category

Here is the exception in my log:

> Exception: [IMF_Category] - System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type IMF_Main_Category is not part of the model for the current context.
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)

**Update**

I have checked other questions before posting but they don't seem to provide the right answer for my situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "The entity type <model> is not part of the model for the current context."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394603/getting-the-entity-type-model-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-contex)

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl I have checked other questions before posting but they don't seem to provide the right answer for my situation